# ASP.NET MVC and Mootools

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mootools

Do you know of any examples of MooTools and ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/thiagosantos/archive/2009/01/05/mootools-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) of ASP.NET MVC with Mootools.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC includes JQuery which seems to have Microsofts approval.  However there really isn't a great deal of overlap (as yet) with the client side Javascript framework and the server-side MVC architecture specifically.

The use of JQuery, MooTools or any other such framework when delivering Views is realy quite independant of MVC itself.  What you would probably be more interested in is how MooTools might integrate with ASP.NET AJAX which may I guess be considered a component of MVC.

Here this one [blog](http://ifwdev.wordpress.com/2007/06/07/ajaxnet-professional-with-mootools-part-2/) on ASP.NET AJAX and MooTools.

Note though that MS are putting quite a bit of effort into adding intellisense support for JQuery into VS2008.  Its quite possible that a third party might put the same effort into supporting MooTools in intellisense but then they might not, something worth considering if you're not too tied to MooTools.